# Combining a word array and a vector array to make a Gensim W2V model

Tags: gensim, word2vec, embedding, word-embedding

I have a word array from a pickle file, and a corresponding vector array from an npy file, how do I combine them to make a Gensim W2V model?

Answer (score 0):

That's not enough to make a full `Word2Vec` model instance, which is usually created via a survey of, & then training of, a text corpus. (Those steps also compile necessary word frequencies & train internal model weights that aren't part of a set of word-vectors.)

You could create a `gensim` `KeyedVectors` instance of the right dimensionality, then use its [`.add()`](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.Word2VecKeyedVectors.add) method to add your values.  That requires you have a list of the words, and the array of vectors, in the same order. This would allow lots of standard operations on the word-vectors, like `.most_similar()`, but not further word2vec-training.

For example:

```py
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
kv = KeyedVectors(vector_size)
kv.add(list_of_words, array_of_vectors)
print(kv.most_similar('apple'))
```